# Create file in python dynamically

Tags: python

I know it's a noob question but I have some difficulties to make it works

```
def create(file):
    f = open(file,'w')
```

it returns "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "

If I do that it works of course:

```
file ="myfile"
f = open(file,'w')
```

But I can't figure out how to create my file from the function parameter

Sorry for the noob question, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you pass to `file` at the first function? Also you are missing ' after the `w`

Comment: I pass a simple string.

I tried file = str(file) before passing it to open it doesn't change anything

Comment: The reported error will occur is `file` (**terrible** name to use BTW) is a path including non-existent directories -- `open` doesn't auto-create such directories (see `os.makedirs(os.dirname(file))` for that, and use `try`/`except` around it to catch the exception if the directory exists).

Comment: open do autocreate a file when I define it like that before file= "myfilename" that's what I don't understand.
I don't want to create any directory, just a file

Comment: @François Richard 1. you should close the file at the end, 2. If you pass a string like "test" it will create the file at the current run folder, so you probably pass a folder path that doesn't exists.

Comment: what does file look like when you pass it to the function?

Comment: The string is an http link, ie: 'http://somesite.com

Edit: @Padraic this was the problem, it works when I trunc the 'http://', subsidiary question what would I have to save the whole string with http:// too ? Post your comment as answer I'll validate it, thanks !

Comment: you know that sites can look like paths to the operating system, right? for instance: `stackoverflow.com/something` will be interpreted as having a subdirectory `stackoverflow.com` in which there is a file `something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you pass the `"http://somesite.com/"` as file to your function  python treats it as a directory structure.

As soon as python gets to `"http:/"` it presumes we have a directory. Using forward slashes in unix is not allowed and I imagine it is the same for windows.

To turn the name into something useable you can use some variation of urlparse.urlsplit:

```
import urlparse

import urlparse
def parse(f):
    prse  = urlparse.urlsplit(f)
    return prse.netloc if f.startswith("http") else prse.path.split("/",1)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sites can look like paths to directories to the operating system. for instance: `stackoverflow.com/something` will be interpreted as a directory `stackoverflow.com` in which there is a file `something`.

You can see this when you use [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
>>> os.path.dirname('stackoverflow.com/something')
'stackoverflow.com'
```

If this is indeed the case, and you still want to proceed, you're passing a path to a location in a directory and not just a file name.

You have to make sure the directory `stackoverflow.com` exists first:

```
file_path = 'stackoverflow.com/something'
dirname = os.path.dirname(file_path)

if not os.path.exists(dirname):
    # if stackoverflow.com directory does not exist it will be created
    os.makedirs(dirname)

# .. carry on to open file_path and use it.
```

Watch out from `http://` and the likes and consider using a real url parser.

**tip:** `file` is already defined in python, you shouldn't override it by using it to name a variable.

Comment: I just want to create a file

Answer (score 1):

Editing:

```
def create(file):
    f = open(file,'w')
    f.close()
```

If you call this function using:

```
create('myfile.txt')
```

It will create a file named `myfile.txt` in whatever directory the code is being run from.  Note that you are passing in a `string` not an `object`.

Since I now see you are passing in a string similar to `http://www.google.com`, you are trying to create a file named `www.google.com` in the `http:` folder.  You are going to have to truncate or change the `/` since Windows files cannot contain that character in their names.

We'll use everything after the last `/` in this example:

```
def create(filename):
    filename = re.sub(r'.*//*', '', filename)
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.close()
```

So calling: `create('www.google.com/morestuff/things')` will create a file called `things`

Comment: I know this solution is working my problem is that it doesn't work when the file name come from the function parameter.

def create(file):
    f = open(file,'w')

Comment: Okay, then we'll need to see more of your code so we know what you are passing into the function.